# Different cipher using AES in java stored function in Oracle and on desktop

Tags: java, oracle, encryption, oracle11g, aes

I have an trouble, that I can't resolve for a long time. I make AES cipher with the same code in Oracle java stored function and on Desktop:

```
String keyAlg = "AES";
String cipherAlg = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
byte[] data = new byte[]{14,23,3,45,62};
byte[] pswdBytes = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,6};
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(pswdBytes);


Key key = new SecretKeySpec(hash , keyAlg);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherAlg);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encVal = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

Different outputs:

B38D521183**00**A8F56A712080616C351B – in Oracle

B38D521183**74**A8F56A712080616C351B – on PC

Can you explain where I've made mistake or have not properly set anything.

And if I try to decrypt cipher text, I catch exception with 'Oracle cipher text', and all is Ok with cipher text from PC.

P.S.: Oracle version: Oracle DB 11g Enterprise 11.2.0.4.0, 
      jdk1.6.0_43

Comment: I've installed Oracle 12, and there is no problem like that. But I should support this functionality on Oracle 11

Comment: Are you sure the plaintexts are byte-equal? This could be a situation where the input appears the same lexicographically but uses a different byte value representation in the given encoding (i.e. homographs like Latin `A` (`0x29`) and Cyrillic `А` (`0x0410`)). Compare the raw byte values of both plaintexts and the encodings.

Comment: @Andy, It was my first suppose, but it wasn't correct. In my code you can see that I try to cipher raw byte value (byte arrays in java), so there aren't place for an Encoding/Decoding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found answer for my question, when i've tried to cipher data in Oracle 12, there are similar results like as on PC. So I think it's a problem with Oracle 11.